# Deployed nopcommerce on IIS7.5 Logged in customer showed blank page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5, nopcommerce, .net-framework-version

I am working on nocpommerce 2.40. I have successfully converted and ran application in mvc5 environment with framework 4.5. I have also deployed my application on my local IIS 7.5.

Application runs smoothly when no user is logged in i.e for guest user, but as soon I login, blank page is displayed after reloading.

There isnt any error in the log table of my db. Though error in console is there which is

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Any solutions